# Is virtual function call slower than dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++

I know that dynamic_cast has a serious cost, but when I try the following codes, I get a bigger value almost every time from virtual function call loop. Do I know wrong until this time?

EDIT: The problem was that my compiler had been in debug mode. When I switched to release mode, virtual function call loop runs 5 to 7 times faster than dynamic_cast loop.

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() {}
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual void foo() override {}
};

struct C : public B {
    virtual void foo() override {}
};

int main()
{
    vector<A *> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        if (i % 2)
            vec.push_back(new C());
        else
            vec.push_back(new B());

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (auto iter : vec)
        if (dynamic_cast<C*>(iter))
            ;
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout << (static_cast<double>(end) - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    begin = clock();
    for (auto iter : vec)
        iter->foo();
    end = clock();

    cout << (static_cast<double>(end) - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you compile in release, with compiler optimization?

Comment: If I were a compiler writer trying to implement `dynamic_cast`, I'd do it by creating a hidden virtual function! Unlikely to be faster than calling a virtual function directly.

Comment: I suspect that the compiler has removed the dynamic cast, since its result isn't used.

Comment: Dynamic cast is potentially slower if you use it to replace virtual dispatch, which your code does not do.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the compiler bothers to generate instructions for your `dynamic_cast` loop?

Comment: Given the many different things the optimizer might do or not do in different situations, I'm not sure it's very worthwhile to try to test things like this with an artificial test program; any results you observe probably won't be applicable outside of the artificial test case.  Better to modify your own actual program to use one or the other, and test your actual use case to see whether one approach is measurably faster than the other *in your actual use case*.  My suspicion is you will find that performance-wise, the difference is too small to measure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything with the result of the `dynamic_cast` in the lines

```
for (auto iter : vec)
    if (dynamic_cast<C*>(iter))
        ;
```

the compiler might be optimizing away most of that code if not all of it.

If you do something useful with the result of the `dynamic_cast`, you might see a difference. You could try:

```
for (auto iter : vec)
{
    if (C* cptr = dynamic_cast<C*>(iter))
    {
        cptr->foo();
    }
    if (B* bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(iter))
    {
        bptr->foo();
    }
}
```

That will most likely make a difference.

See http://ideone.com/BvqoqU for a sample run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I found the problem and wrote it as an edit. In addition, the point is not your mentioned because I had tried to use of dynamic_cast 's return value and it does not change anything.

Comment: @RainMan14, discarding the result of `dynamic_cast` should make a significant difference. See http://ideone.com/tYiZKc and compare with the results in the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I know wrong until this time?

We probably can not tell from your code.  The optimizer is clever, and it is some times quite challenging to 'defeat' or 'deceive' it.

In the following, I use 'assert()' to try to control the optimizer's enthusiasm.  Also note that 'time(0)' is a fast function on Ubuntu 15.10. I believe the compiler does not yet know what the combination will do, and thus will not remove it, providing a more reliable/repeatable measurement.

I think I like these results better, and perhaps these indicate that dynamic cast **is** slower than virtual function invocation.

Environment:

```
on an older Dell, using Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit, and -O3 

~$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1 20151028
```

Results (dynamic cast followed by virtual funtion):

```
  void T523_t::testStruct()

  0.443445

  0.184873


  void T523_t::testClass()

   252,495 us

   184,961 us

  FINI   2914399 us
```

Code:

```
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // std-chrono-hi-res-clk-time-point
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
using   namespace std::chrono_literals;          // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>


// original ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct A {
   virtual ~A() = default; // warning: ‘struct A’ has virtual functions and
                      // accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
   virtual void foo() { assert(time(0)); }
};


struct B : public A {
   virtual void foo() override { assert(time(0)); }
};

struct C : public B {
    virtual void foo() override { assert(time(0)); }
};


// with class ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// If your C++ code has no class ... why bother?
class A_t {
public:
   virtual ~A_t() = default; // warning: ‘struct A’ has virtual functions and
                      // accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
   virtual void foo() { assert(time(0)); }
};

class B_t : public A_t {
public:
   virtual void foo() override { assert(time(0)); }
};

class C_t : public B_t {
public:
   virtual void foo() override { assert(time(0)); }
};



class T523_t
{
public:

   T523_t() = default;
   ~T523_t() = default;

   int exec()
      {
         testStruct();

         testClass();

         return(0);
      }

private: // methods

   std::string digiComma(std::string s)
      {  //vvvvv--sSize must be signed int of sufficient size
         int32_t sSize = static_cast<int32_t>(s.size());
         if (sSize > 3)
            for (int32_t indx = (sSize - 3); indx > 0; indx -= 3)
               s.insert(static_cast<size_t>(indx), 1, ',');
         return(s);
      }


   void testStruct()
      {
         using std::vector;
         using std::cout; using std::endl;

         std::cout << "\n\n  " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

         vector<A *> vec;
         for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
            if (i % 2)
               vec.push_back(new C());
            else
               vec.push_back(new B());

         clock_t begin = clock();
         int i=0;
         for (auto iter : vec)
         {
            if(i % 2) (assert(dynamic_cast<C*>(iter))); // if (dynamic_cast<C*>(iter)) {};
            else      (assert(dynamic_cast<B*>(iter)));
         }

         clock_t end = clock();
         cout << "\n  " << std::setw(8)
              << ((static_cast<double>(end)  -  static_cast<double>(begin))
                  / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // warning: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘clock_t {aka long int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]

         begin = clock();
         for (auto iter : vec)
            iter->foo();
         end = clock();

         cout << "\n  " << std::setw(8)
              << ((static_cast<double>(end)  -  static_cast<double>(begin))
                  / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // warning: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘clock_t {aka long int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
      }


   void testClass()
      {
         std::cout << "\n\n  " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
         std::vector<A_t *> APtrVec;
         for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
         {
            if (i % 2)   APtrVec.push_back(new C_t());
            else         APtrVec.push_back(new B_t());
         }

         {
            Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();
            int i = 0;
            for (auto Aptr : APtrVec)
            {
               if(i % 2) assert(dynamic_cast<C_t*>(Aptr)); // check for nullptr
               else      assert(dynamic_cast<B_t*>(Aptr)); // check for nullptr
               ++i;
            }
            auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);
            std::cout << "\n  " << std::setw(8)
                      << digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
                      << " us" << std::endl;
         }

         {
            Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();
            for (auto Aptr : APtrVec) {
               Aptr->foo();
            }
            auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);
            std::cout << "\n  " << std::setw(8)
                      << digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
                      << " us" << std::endl;
         }
      }

}; // class T523_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::cout << "\nargc: " << argc << std::endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1) std::cout << argv[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
   { time_t t0 = std::time(nullptr); while(t0 == time(nullptr)) { /**/ }; }

   Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T523_t   t523;
      retVal = t523.exec();
   }

   auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

   std::cout << "\n  FINI   " << (std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
             << " us" << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

---

update 2017-08-31

I suspect many of you will object to performing the dynamic cast without using the result.  Here is one possible approach by replacing the for-auto loop in testClass() method:

```
for (auto Aptr : APtrVec)
{
   if(i % 2) { C_t* c = dynamic_cast<C_t*>(Aptr); assert(c); c->foo(); }
   else      { B_t* b = dynamic_cast<B_t*>(Aptr); assert(b); b->foo(); }
   ++i;
}
```

With results

```
  void T523_t::testStruct()

  0.443445

  0.184873


  void T523_t::testClass()

   322,431 us

   191,285 us


  FINI   4156941 us
```

end update

---

Comment: The measured durations change from run to run, but the dynamic cast duration is always longer than virtual function duration measurement.  I only grabbed one snapshot of results.  Your results will vary.